# DynamoDB filter condition and Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, dynamo-local

Can anyone help me to understand what is the best approach to handle condition filtering and Limit

I'm using dynanmodb to store some products and I want to use pagination with them.
Because some of the products are enabled I got to filter based on a field.

no problem until there.

When I use Limit, if I want to Limit the data to be returned the Limit will be applied after the query makes the filtering.

Here is the deal :
All the time the query will return the data and Limit based on the last item to top first one, and I get the Key to make the pagination to the top.

If I would like to retrieve from the top to the bottom I Will set Scan Index Forward = true, and do the same as the other query.

But I would like to get random products and do the pagination because I don't I apply something like that, all the time the same products from the first one to the bottom or unlike. but what about the products in the middle etc?

I'm using a simple schema :
PK: PRODS
SK: ITEM#RamdomID

thanks a lot, I appreciate any helpful comment.

Comment: Probably need to change the schema bit, what is the field you filtering on?

Comment: if the item is enabled = true will be returned the product